# How to remove gap between a frame and its scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have three frames; left_frame, middle_frame and right_frame. I would like to have no gap between left_frame and its scrollbar. How can I achieve it?

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def create_dummy_chart(frame, index):
    # Create a dummy chart
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=f"Chart {index}", width=10, height=2, relief="solid")
    label.pack(side="top", pady=5)

# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Chart Display")
window.geometry("800x300")

# Create the left frame
left_frame = tk.Frame(window, width=200, height=300, relief="solid", bd=1)
left_frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")

# Create a canvas to hold the left_frame and the scrollbar
canvas = tk.Canvas(left_frame, width=200, height=300)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="y")

# Create the scrollbar
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(left_frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

# Configure the canvas to use the scrollbar
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

# Create a frame inside the canvas to hold the charts
chart_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

# Add the frame to the canvas
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=chart_frame, anchor="nw")

# Create dummy charts in the chart_frame
num_charts = 200
for i in range(num_charts):
    create_dummy_chart(chart_frame, i)

# Update the canvas scrollable area
chart_frame.update_idletasks()
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

# Create the middle frame
middle_frame = tk.Frame(window, width=200, height=300, relief="solid", bd=1)
middle_frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")

# Create the right frame
right_frame = tk.Frame(window, width=400, height=300, relief="solid", bd=1)
right_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

# Run the Tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

I have left_frame and vertical scrollabr. But, I ended up having a gap between them. I expect to have no gap between them. How can I achieve this?

What I have:

[image]

What I expect:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're referring to the one or two pixel space between the canvas and the scrollbar**, you can set the `highlightthickness` attribute of the canvas to zero, or you can set the `highlightcolor` to the same color as the background of the canvas so that the highlight ring is not visible when the canvas has the keyboard focus.

You might also need to explicitly set the `padx` value to zero when packing the canvas and scrollbar. On some platforms it might default to 1.

**If you're referring to the fact that the canvas is wider than the items in the canvas**, then you can set up a binding to set the width of the canvas to always match the width of the items on the canvas.

You can do that like this:

```
chart_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: canvas.configure(width=chart_frame.winfo_width()))
```

Comment: I refer to this: **If you're referring to the one or two pixel space between the canvas and the scrollbar,** I tried both methods separately, and then all together. But, unfortunately, it did not work. There is still some gap between images that are shown and the scrollbar. In my case, there are no gaps between frame and scrolbar. My example is reproducible, so you can se the result. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @dsapprentice: what do you mean by "gap between images". You asked about a gap between the scrollbar and frame, so your statement _"In my case, there are no gaps between frame and scrollbar"_  is puzzling.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added photos to clarify my expectation.

Comment: @dsapprentice: this answer solves that problem with the bit of code at the end of the answer. The problem is that your canvas is wider than the items in the canvas.

Comment: then, I shold apply this for each frame I have, right?

Comment: @dsapprentice: I don't know what you're asking. If you embed multiple frames inside a canvas, it becomes a little more complex. The bottom line is simply that you've made the canvas too wide.