# How to match the width of the items on the canvas with the width of the canvas in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Using the following script, I can create my expected layout. However, I would like to match the width of the items on the canvas with the width of the canvas in tkinter. I would like to do that for canvas and items in left_frame and right_frame.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Create the main Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Radial Charts")
root.geometry("1200x600")

# Create the main frame
main_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

# Create the dropdown menu
dropdown_frame = ttk.Frame(main_frame)
dropdown_frame.pack()

# String variable to store the selected option
selected_option = tk.StringVar(root)

# Dropdown menu options
options = ["Female","Male"]

# Create the dropdown menu
dropdown_style = ttk.Style()
dropdown_style.configure("Custom.TMenubutton", background="#faf2ca", font=("TkDefaultFont", 18))

dropdown = ttk.OptionMenu(dropdown_frame, selected_option, options[0], *options, style="Custom.TMenubutton")
dropdown.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

# Center the dropdown menu at the top
dropdown_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
dropdown_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

# Create the left frame with a scrollbar
left_frame = ttk.Frame(main_frame)
left_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Create a canvas for the radial charts
canvas = tk.Canvas(left_frame, width=200, height=300)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Create a vertical scrollbar for the radial charts canvas
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(left_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

# Configure the canvas to use the scrollbar
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')))

# Create a frame inside the canvas to hold the radial charts
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor=tk.NW)

# Create the middle frames
middle_frame = ttk.Frame(main_frame)
middle_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10)

upper_middle_frame = ttk.Frame(middle_frame)
upper_middle_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

lower_middle_frame = ttk.Frame(middle_frame)
lower_middle_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Create the right frame for the radial chart
right_frame = ttk.Frame(main_frame)
right_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Create a canvas for the radial charts
right_canvas = tk.Canvas(right_frame)
right_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Create a vertical scrollbar for the radial charts canvas
scrollbar2 = ttk.Scrollbar(right_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
scrollbar2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

# Create a canvas for the right frame
right_canvas = tk.Canvas(right_frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)
right_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Configure the scrollbar and canvas
scrollbar2.config(command=right_canvas.yview)
right_canvas.config(scrollregion=right_canvas.bbox("all"))

# Create a frame inside the canvas to hold the images
right_canvas_frame = tk.Frame(right_canvas)
right_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=right_canvas_frame, anchor=tk.NW)


# # Configure the canvas to use the scrollbar
# right_canvas = tk.Canvas(right_frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)
# right_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
# right_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: right_canvas.configure(scrollregion=right_canvas.bbox('all')))

# # Configure the canvas to use the scrollbar
# right_canvas = tk.Canvas(right_frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)
# right_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

scrollbar2.config(command=right_canvas.yview)

# Create a canvas for the line plot
line_plot_canvas = tk.Canvas(upper_middle_frame, width=600, height=600, background='white')
line_plot_canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)

# Create a canvas for the data table
data_table_canvas = tk.Canvas(lower_middle_frame, width=600, height=600, background='white')
data_table_canvas.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH)

# Global elements for line plot and data table
line_plot_image_tk = None
table_image_tk = None


def generate_line_plot_path(start_visit, end_visit):
    line_plot_path = f"path/line_plot_{start_visit}_and_{end_visit}.png"
    return line_plot_path


def display_line_plot(start_visit, end_visit):
    global line_plot_image_tk

    line_plot_path = generate_line_plot_path(start_visit, end_visit)
    line_plot_image = Image.open(line_plot_path)
    line_plot_image = line_plot_image.resize((900, 600), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Adjust the size as needed
    line_plot_image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(line_plot_image)

    # Clear the line plot canvas
    line_plot_canvas.delete("all")

    # Display the resized line plot image on the canvas
    line_plot_canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=line_plot_image_tk)


def display_table_chart(table_image_path):
    global table_image_tk

    if table_image_path:
        table_image = Image.open(table_image_path)
        table_image = table_image.resize((600, 800), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Adjust the size as needed
        table_image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(table_image)

        # Clear the data table canvas
        data_table_canvas.delete("all")

        # Create a label to display the table chart image
        table_label = tk.Label(data_table_canvas, image=table_image_tk)
        table_label.pack()

        data_table_canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, window=table_label)
        data_table_canvas.update_idletasks()  # Update the canvas


# Function to handle checkbox selection
def checkbox_selected():
    selected_checkbuttons = [cb for cb, var in checkbuttons if var.get() == 1]
    if len(selected_checkbuttons) >= 2:
        start_visit = int(selected_checkbuttons[0]["text"].split("_")[1])
        print('Start Visit',start_visit)
        end_visit = int(selected_checkbuttons[1]["text"].split("_")[1])
        print('End Visit', end_visit)
        display_line_plot(start_visit, end_visit)

        for radiobutton in radiobuttons:
            visit_number = int(radiobutton["text"].split("_")[1])
            print(visit_number)
            if start_visit-1 <= visit_number <= end_visit-1:
                radiobutton.select()
            else:
                radiobutton.deselect()

        if "visit_1" in selected_checkbuttons[0]["text"] and "visit_2" in selected_checkbuttons[1]["text"]:
            display_table_chart("path/table_1_2.png")
        elif "visit_2" in selected_checkbuttons[0]["text"] and "visit_3" in selected_checkbuttons[1]["text"]:
            display_table_chart("path/table_2_3.png")
        elif "visit_3" in selected_checkbuttons[0]["text"] and "visit_4" in selected_checkbuttons[1]["text"]:
            display_table_chart("path/table_3_4.png")
        elif "visit_4" in selected_checkbuttons[0]["text"] and "visit_5" in selected_checkbuttons[1]["text"]:
            display_table_chart("path/table_4_5.png")
        elif "visit_5" in selected_checkbuttons[0]["text"] and "visit_6" in selected_checkbuttons[1]["text"]:
            display_table_chart("path/table_5_6.png")
        elif "visit_6" in selected_checkbuttons[0]["text"] and "visit_7" in selected_checkbuttons[1]["text"]:
            display_table_chart("path/table_6_7.png")
        elif "visit_7" in selected_checkbuttons[0]["text"] and "visit_8" in selected_checkbuttons[1]["text"]:
            display_table_chart("path/table_7_8.png")
        elif "visit_8" in selected_checkbuttons[0]["text"] and "visit_9" in selected_checkbuttons[1]["text"]:
            display_table_chart("path/table_8_9.png")
    else:
        # Clear the line plot and table chart displays
        display_line_plot([], [])
        display_table_chart("")



# Load and display the radial charts
checkbuttons = []  # List to store the checkbuttons

for i in range(1, 10):
    image_path = f"path/visit_{i}.png"  # Replace with the actual image path

    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Adjust the size as needed
    image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    # Create a label to display the image
    label = tk.Label(frame, image=image_tk)
    label.pack()

    # Keep a reference to the image to prevent it from being garbage collected
    label.image = image_tk

    # Create an IntVar for each Checkbutton
    check_var = tk.IntVar()

    # Create a Checkbutton and place it on the bottom-right part of the image
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(label, text=f"visit_{i}", variable=check_var, command=checkbox_selected)
    checkbutton.place(relx=1, rely=1, anchor=tk.SE)

    checkbuttons.append((checkbutton, check_var))  # Add the checkbutton and its associated variable to the list

# Load and display the radial charts for multi visits

# Load and display the radial charts
selected_visit_var = tk.StringVar()  # Variable to store the selected visit
selected_visit_var.set("")  # Initialize the variable
radiobuttons = []  # List to store the checkbuttons
selected_radiobutton = None  # Variable to store the selected radiobutton
for i in range(1, 9):
    image_path = f"path/visit_{i}_and_{i+1}.png"  # Replace with the actual image path

    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Adjust the size as needed
    image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    # Create a label to display the image
    label = tk.Label(right_canvas_frame, image=image_tk)
    label.pack()

    # Keep a reference to the image to prevent it from being garbage collected
    label.image = image_tk

    # Create a Radiobutton for each visit
    radiobutton = tk.Radiobutton(
        label,
        text=f"visit_{i}",
        variable=selected_visit_var,
        value=f"visit_{i}",
        command=checkbox_selected
    )
    radiobutton.place(relx=1, rely=1, anchor=tk.SE)

    radiobuttons.append(radiobutton)  # Add the radiobutton to the list
# Bind the canvas to the scrollbar
right_canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: right_canvas.config(scrollregion=right_canvas.bbox("all")))
right_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)
# right_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
# scrollbar2.pack(side="right", fill="y")

# # Start the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

To achieve this mathcing of items on the canvas with the width of the canvas, I used the following lines just before the  `root.mainloop()`

I set up a binding per @Bryan Oakley's answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76382914/how-to-remove-gap-between-a-frame-and-its-scrollbar/76385022#76385022).

When I apply the following line, left_frame slides right side of the screen and cover the whole screen.

```py
....
left_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: canvas.configure(width=left_frame.winfo_width()))
root.mainloop()
```

I f I apply, the width of the items on the canvas gets bigger than the canvas.

```py
....
right_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: right_canvas.configure(width=right_frame.winfo_width()))
root.mainloop()
```

How can I set the binding correctly so that width of the items on the canvas of left_frame matches with the width of the canvas? I want to achieve the same result with right_canvas, too.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Do you want the width of the *frame* inside left canvas the same as the width of left canvas?

Comment: @acw1668 exactly, that is what I want

Comment: Unfortunately, I keep getting same output after applying your suggestion. I also tried using e.winfo_width(), but still same output with my original one happens.

Comment: which version of python, and tkinter are you using? I use python 3.10

Comment: Try `canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.itemconfig(frame_id, width=e.width)` where `frame_id` is the result of `canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=frame, ...)`.

Comment: this works like a charm. But scrollbar, dark rectangle disappears after I use this code. How can I prevent the rectangle to disappear? Note that I use this line just before root.mainloop()

Comment: Is it possible for you to make the example smaller, and not rely on external images? There also seems to be a lot of code unrelated to the problem being asked. For example, do we need the functions that are called when clicking on the checkboxes, since you're asking a layout question rather than a computation question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a frame inside of a canvas to be the width of the canvas itself, you can set a binding on the `<Configure>` event of the canvas. This event fires whenever something about the canvas itself changes - location, size, etc. When the event triggers, you can configure the width of the frame using the width of the canvas.

The following example illustrates the point by putting a canvas in a frame, and then another frame inside the canvas. When the canvas changes size, the width of the inner frame will be resized to fit.

The example uses a paned window so that you can change the size of the left frame. When you move the sash, the `<Configure>` event of the canvas will be triggered, causing the inner frame to be resized to fit the width of the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

pw = tk.PanedWindow(root, orient="horizontal", sashrelief="raised", showhandle=True)
pw.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

left_frame = tk.Frame(bg="pink")
right_frame = tk.Frame(bg="pink")

pw.add(left_frame)
pw.add(right_frame)

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(left_frame, bg="lightgreen", width=100, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
inner_frame = tk.Frame(canvas1, bg="lightblue", height=100, bd=2, relief="raised")
canvas1.create_window(0, 0, window=inner_frame, anchor="nw", tag="inner_frame")

def resize_frame(event):
    canvas=event.widget       # canvas that generated the event
    width = event.width       # width of the canvas
    frame_id = "inner_frame"  # defined when we added the window to the canvas

    canvas.itemconfigure(frame_id, width=width)

canvas1.bind("<Configure>", resize_frame)

tk.mainloop()
```

Note: in the following screenshots, the canvas is green and the inner frame is blue.

[image: initial screenshot]
[image: screenshot after resizing]