# Expand my internal frame to the same size of the canvas

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

for some reason setting the internal frame to the size of canvas not working. it was start to happend because I wanted to add scrollbars.(and that required to add many widget one inside the other.)
so my window looks like in the image attached.
I think it occured due to the line - `Canvas_name.create_window(0, 0, window=internal_frame, anchor="nw")` becuase if I use pack on the internal window instead it looks as i wish but it also makes the scrollbar not working.

I attach my code.

Please let me know what Im missing.
Thanks much.

```
[import tkinter.ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.constants import *

import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table

root = Tk()
New_Tab = Toplevel(root)
tab_control = tkinter.ttk.Notebook(New_Tab)
Tab = tkinter.ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(Tab, text='TAB1')
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both') # changed from grid() to pack()
New_Tab.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # changed row 1 to 0
New_Tab.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frames_in_tabs = tkinter.ttk.Frame(Tab)
parent_frame = frames_in_tabs
canvas_names = Canvas(parent_frame)
ver_widget_name = "_VerScrBar"
hor_widget_name = "_HorScrBar"
ver_sb = tkinter.ttk.Scrollbar(Tab, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas_names.yview, name=ver_widget_name)
hor_sb = tkinter.ttk.Scrollbar(Tab, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=canvas_names.xview, name=hor_widget_name)
ver_sb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
hor_sb.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
canvas_names.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
canvas_names.configure(yscrollcommand=ver_sb.set)
canvas_names.configure(xscrollcommand=hor_sb.set)
frames_in_tabs.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas_names.configure(scrollregion=canvas_names.bbox("all")))
frames_in_tabs.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
internal_frame = tkinter.ttk.Frame(canvas_names)
canvas_names.create_window(0, 0, window=internal_frame, anchor="nw")
regs_frame = tkinter.ttk.Frame(internal_frame)
fields_frame = tkinter.ttk.Frame(internal_frame)
commands_frame = tkinter.ttk.Label(internal_frame)
info_frame = tkinter.ttk.LabelFrame(internal_frame)
commands_frame.pack(side=LEFT,fill='y')
regs_frame.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=X)
fields_frame.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=X)
info_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM,expand=True,fill=X)
canvas_names.create_window(0, 0, window=internal_frame, anchor="nw")

regs_tables_dict = {}
fields_tables_dict = {}
d= {}
e = {}
for i in range(30):
    d\[f'col_regs{i}'\] = \[1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8\]
    e\[f'col_field{i}'\]=\[9,8,7,5,5,000000,00000\]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dfe = pd.DataFrame(data=e)
parent_frame = regs_frame

block_df = df
regs_tables = Table(parent_frame, dataframe=block_df)
regs_tables.setRowHeight(35)
parent_frame.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand=True,padx=5,pady=5)
regs_tables.show()

parent_frame = fields_frame

block_df = dfe
fields_tables = Table(parent_frame, dataframe=block_df)
fields_tables.setRowHeight(35)
parent_frame.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand=True,padx=5,pady=5)
fields_tables.show()


root.mainloop()]
```

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76425574/7432

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of `internal_frame` to that of `canvas_names` inside the callback of binding `<Configure>` event on `canvas_names`:

```py
...
frame_id = canvas_names.create_window(0, 0, window=internal_frame, anchor="nw")
canvas_names.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: e.widget.itemconfigure(frame_id, width=e.width))
...
```

Note that you have executed `canvas_names.create_window(0, 0, window=internal_frame, anchor="nw")` twice, remove one of them.